# square was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Incurring the **"‘square’ was not declared in this scope"** error while trying to compile a simple program with the "square()" function.

I am doing a "Try this" drill (the "Functions" section) from Stroustrup's *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*, and the code won't compile.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        cout<<i<<'\t'<<square(i)<<'\n';
    }
}
```

And this is what my compile returns:

```
function.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
function.cpp:10:26: error: ‘square’ was not declared in this scope
   cout<<i<<'\t'<<square(i)<<'\n';
```

I made another attempt and placed a function declaration inside of the for-loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        int square(i);
        cout<<i<<'\t'<<square(i)<<'\n';
     }
 }
```

And the reply was:

```
function.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
function.cpp:11:26: error: ‘square’ cannot be used as a function
   cout<<i<<'\t'<<square(i)<<'\n';
```

Besides, I was placing the "square()" function declaration outside the loop inside the body of the "main" and before the body of the "main": the reply was identical to the response to my attempt #2.

The compiler and the OS are:

```
gcc version 5.2.1 20151028 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10)
```

I am a novice, and most probably mistake lies in something very simple -- however I think I have tried all options conceivable. As for the "std_lib_facilities.h" file, it doesn't work and gives a "deprecated header" reply.

I would be **hugely** grateful for any help and advice.

Comment: Did you mean to use `std::sqrt`?  AFAIK there is no `std::square` as you can just do `whatever * whatever`

Comment: What *is* `square`? Where have you defined it? Where is its prototype declared?

Comment: See [here also](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=square&button=) please.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I did commit a stupid mistake by not defining the function _square_. Thank you for reacting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function as square() in cmath. You need pow(base,exp). The following code should compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        cout<<i<<'\t'<<pow(i, 2)<<'\n';
     }
 }
```

Comment: That works, but it's a lot of overhead for computing the square of an integer value. `int square(int x) { return x * x; }`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare and use functions like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int square(int x) {  // function declared and implemented
    return x*x;
}

int main(void) {

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        std::cout<<i<<'\t'<<square(i)<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>

int square(int x);  // function prototype

int main(void) {

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        std::cout<<i<<'\t'<<square(i)<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

int square(int x) {   // function definition/implementation
    return x*x;
}
```

But for a simple piece of code like this it's not worth making a function - instead you can just do `i*i` inside the for loop to achieve the same result without needing to call a function. Alternatively, you could use `pow(x,n)` from `<cmath>` but again that's not really necessary here.

Also note the `++i` in the `for` loop in my example, it's not important here but it's good to learn from the beginning that doing `i++` creates a copy of the variable `i` then increments it - whereas doing `++i` does not make a copy. This is irrelevant when `i` is just an integer (for example), but it becomes more important later on when it could be a different entity such as an object which may be more expensive to copy.

Additionally, it's best not to put `using namespace std;` as this creates *namespace pollution* - see here for details:

[Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thank you, ArchbishopOfBanterbury, for your suggestions. Both worked. Initially, I did put i*i instead of function -- but that very exercise required the use of the **square()** function.
I am especially grateful for the **++i vs i++** and **namespace pollution** tips.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is right: neither C nor C++ provides a function named `square` in the standard library. Further, `int square(i);` is not a function declaration. It creates an `int` variable named `square` with an initial value of `i`.

What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: It was supposed to output a table of numbers from 0 to 99 and their squares. Have just fixed that, thank you.